# GitHub clone repositories with SSH doesn't work

Tags: git, github

Type command:

```
git clone git@github.com:Xingggg/Material-Design-Study-Notes.git
```

Terminal error message:

> ```
> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
> ```

I have added my public key in my GitHub account.

I use `HTTPS` clone repositories it's OK.
My machine is MacBook Pro

Comment: Well have you added your public key to a git account with access to that repo? Is that key available in your machine? Does that repo definitely exist? We can't very well guess what's wrong from so little information.

Comment: I have added my public key in my github account. And I use https clone repo It's ok.

Comment: Then it sounds like you haven't configured your machine to use your key correctly.

Comment: I use this public key in the other place It's worked. And I already added public key to github three times, So It's can't be wrong. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"the other place"*. Evidently it can be wrong, because it isn't working.

Comment: Yes And I can't find what's wrong with it. I use public key in  http://www.coding.net, It's GitHub in China.

Comment: And we can't either from the information provided. There are plenty of guides out there for configuring SSH on Mac generally and for GitHub specifically, I can only suggest that you work through the one of those.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you have not set up your ssh keys properly or they might be revoked and you cant use them.

> And I use https clone repo It's ok

`https` use username password and not ssh. Set the keys and switch the remote to ssh.

---

### ***`Here is how to set it up:`***

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key as you mentioned )
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

### ***`How to set up ssh key under your GitHub account?`***

- Login to GitHub account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (***`Settings`***)
  [image]
- Click on the `SSH keys and GPG Keys`
  [image]
- Click on the `New SSH key`
  [image]
- Paste your key and save

Now it should work

---

### ***`Note`***

After the first set up open terminal and run a `git fetch` so the key will be tested and added to your `known hosts` file.

Comment: Set SSH key is right. Because I use the same key in the coding.net. The coding is git server like GitHub in China. I was in China, So I think the reason is the Great Firewall of China.

Comment: Cool, so can you pass the wall now? ;-) Feel free to accept and vote for the answer. Appricated

Comment: Yeah, I use Shadowsocks to pass the GFC. But only chrome can work with Shadowsocks. The others app like Google Drive in my computer doesn't work. If I want to use the Local app pass GFC I must download some proxy software and config it. But sometimes I have to return CFC to use some server in China.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same SSH Public key in the coding.net.

The Coding is git server like GitHub in China.

I was in China, So I think the reason is the Great Firewall of China.

Comment: If others people in Mainland China come up with the same problem as you,you can say it's because of Great Firewall.But I have successfully cloned repository in PRC several times.

Comment: I don't know. Because I successfully cloned repository in my company, But failed in my home. And I does not change my config file.

Comment: I can clone repository using ssh,in ShangHai and BeiJing.