# For git,how to know whether the network support ssh or https?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm using a new network.But when I tried to clone repositories from Github,
`git clone git@github.com:myname/projectname.git` failed.It shows:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
>   fatal:Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have created the repository in Github.

But `git clone https://github.com/myname/projectname.git` succeeded.

So,does this mean that my network only support https not ssh?Or is there anything more I need to do to say it?

I'm using Git bash in win7,my git version is 2.9.0.My location is ShangHai China.I'm using VPN,I have access to youtube,google and so on.

Comment: I have add the output.@AD7six

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your ssh [GitHub setup is complete](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) (that is your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key is registered to your GitHub account)

Then, make sure to use the latest git available ([On Windows: 2.9.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

It can be a firewall issue (either local or remote, depending on your country: see [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818847/6309))
Switching to an https url can be a good workaround.

Comment: If I can clone repository successfully,does that mean I have my public key registered to my GitHub account?@VonC

Comment: @YuanWen if you are using an ssh url, yes. If you are using an https url, no. Even before cloning, you can test https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Comment: @YuanWen But first, what OS are you using? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: I have added the public key,but in my GitHub account's personal settings,it shows the key 'Never Used'.I'm using windows7 and git 2.9.0@Vonc

Comment: @YuanWen Sure, you can unzip to check if the issue persists: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.2-64-bit.7z.exe

Comment: @YuanWen also, are you using `git-cmd.exe` or `git-bash.exe`?

Comment: @YuanWen OK. Do you see your private and public key in `ls -alrth ~/.ssh`

Comment: Yes,I can see id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.@VonC

Comment: @YuanWen OK. Are you cloning that GitHub repo from China? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36818847/6309)

Comment: Yes,ShangHai China,but my company is using VPN service.@VonC

Comment: @YuanWen you can also try https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/